# FB.ui dialog appears at the top of the page rather than centered at current scroll position

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

FB.ui dialog appears at the top of the page rather than centered at current scroll position.

1. Person scrolls down to the page
2. Clicks `share`
3. `FB.ui` dialog appears at the top of the page (person doesn't see it)

Code is as simple as:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://[..].com/app/' + app_id,
});
```

Do I need to/Can I call any method to adjust the position of the dialog element?

Note that content is added dynamically to the page, thus it might be that FB script doesn't know what is the current window size.